# Updating two tables with same data where there is no relationship (PK,FK) between those tables

Tags: postgresql

```
update Claim
set first_name = random_name(7), 
    Last_name = random_name(6),
    t2.first_name=random_name(7),
    t2.last_name=random_name(6)
from Claim t1
inner join tbl_ecpremit t2
on t1.first_name = t2.first_name
```

I am getting below error

```
column "t2" of relation "claim" does not exist
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do. Do you want to update table "claim" from data in table "tbl_ecpremit" or do you want to insert the same new data in both tables?

Comment: I want to insert updated new data in to both tables.

Comment: Unrelated but: remove the `from Claim tb1`. [Quote from the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html): "*Note that the target table must **not** appear in the from_list, unless you intend a self-join (in which case it must appear with an alias in the from_list)*" - do you really intend a self-join here? You can also not update two different tables with a single UPDATE statement even if both tables are part of the join condition

Comment: Can you give me updated query.i dint understand what ur saying in above comment.

Comment: in both table first and last name should be same after updating both tables.

Comment: You should specify your question MUCH BETTER. As it is now, no-one will be able to answer this question as you do not appear to understand your problem yourself (see comments to answer below).

Comment: example if we update frist_name='XX' in claim table the same should be updated in tbl_ecpremit .means both tales frist_name values should be 'XX'

Comment: Please read my example which i have written in above comment

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a so-called [data-modifying CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```
WITH c AS (
  UPDATE claim SET first_name = random_name(7), last_name = random_name(6)
  WHERE <put your condition here>
  RETURNING *
)
UPDATE tbl_ecpremit SET last_name = c.last_name
FROM c
WHERE first_name = c.first_name;
```

This assumes that `random_name()` is a function you define, it is not part of PostgreSQL afaik.

The nifty trick here is that the `UPDATE` in the `WITH` query returns the updated record in the first table using the `RETURNING` clause. You can then use that record in the main `UPDATE` statement to have exactly the same data in the second table.

This is all very precarious though, because you are both linking on and modifying the "first_name" column with some random value. In real life this will only work well if you have some more logic regarding the names and conditions.

Comment: Not Insert. I want to update the tables.if i update claim table first and last name same values should be updated in tbl_ecpremit table

Comment: claim  table is updating ,i dont think tbl_ecpremit  will update.

Comment: Unless you can be very specific about what you want, you will not get a proper answer.

Comment: in both table first and last name should be same after updating both tables

Comment: example  if we update frist_name='XX' in claim table the same should be updated in tbl_ecpremit .means both tales frist_name values should be 'XX'

Comment: example if we update frist_name='XX' in claim table the same should be updated in tbl_ecpremit .means both tales frist_name values should be 'XX'